# Replace body class name attribute in Layout

Tags: magento2, layout, magento2.4, class, magento2.4.4

Is it possible to replace class name value attribute in layout?

for example
body has 3 classes `x y z`
I want it to be
`c y z`

how to replace class x to c

I can add class `c` using
`<attribute name="class" value="c"/>`

the result is body has 4 classes `c x y z`
how to remove the x class ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the template, then you handle this with basic javascript. Make an ajax call to get the class you need and then replace the value by modifying dom.With jquery

```
$(selector).attr(attribute,value)
```

Comment: appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add the below jquery in custom js which is working on page load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').removeClass('x');
});
```

Comment: In my case I would only remove class since the other class already added through layout right?

Comment: @MahmoudM.Abdelmalek check the updated answer.it will just remove the class.